# How to fadein first element and delay 2 sec then fadein next elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to fadein first element and delay 2 sec then fadein next elements ?

On my code , it's will delay 2 sec and then fadein all elements
 in one time.

How can i do ?

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        for (i = 0; i < 40; i++){
            $("#thumbnail" + i).fadeIn("slow");
        }
    }, 2000);
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set timeout for 2 seconds and then fade in elements without any delays in loop, so it is not what you want.

The idea is to call next iteration function after `setTimeout` delay:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nbq6jvoL/).

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var i = 0;
    (function fadeInNext()
    {
        $("#thumbnail" + i).fadeIn("slow");
        console.log("Fading in " + i);
        i++;
        if (i < 40)
        {
            setTimeout(fadeInNext, 2000);
        }
    })();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use the [`.delay`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) function. [`.fadeIn`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) is in the effects queue by default:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    for (i = 0; i < 40; i++){
        $("#thumbnail" + i).delay(2000*i).fadeIn("slow");
    }
});
```

Fiddle Here: http://jsfiddle.net/mnh84ymk/

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     for (i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
         (function (i) {
             setTimeout(function () {
                 $("#thumbnail" + i).fadeIn("slow");
             }, i * 2000);

         })(i)
     }
 });
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mnh84ymk/2/)

Comment: All `.fadeIn()` will be executed at once after two seconds delay, won't they?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple programming question. If you know C pretty well, you wouldn't have asked it here.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#thumbnail0").fadeIn("slow");
        setTimeout(function(){
            for (i = 1; i < 40; i++){
                $("#thumbnail" + i).fadeIn("slow");
            }
        }, 2000);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I find this commentary unproductive.

Comment: @thomas I apologize for unnecessary comment. But it really is simple. Even for a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

Use delay with callback:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    fadeInWithDelay(40);

    function fadeInWithDelay(times) {
        if(times == 0) return;
        $('#thumbnail' + i)
            .fadeIn('slow')
            .delay(2000)
            .queue(function (next) {
                fadeInWithDelay(--times);
            });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I made this for you : http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/eym6ennz/

```js
var i = "1";
var testimonialElements = $('div');


$('#link').click(function() {
  $('#thumbnail' + i).fadeIn('fast', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('#thumbnail' + i);
      for (i = 2; i <= testimonialElements.length; i++) {
        var element = testimonialElements.eq(i);
        $('#thumbnail' + i).fadeIn(1000);
      }
    }, 2000);
  });
})
```

```css
#thumbnail1 {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background: green;
  display: none;
}
#thumbnail2 {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background: red;
  display: none;
}
#thumbnail3 {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background: black;
  display: none;
}
#thumbnail4 {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background: grey;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="thumbnail1"></div>
<div id="thumbnail2"></div>
<div id="thumbnail3"></div>
<div id="thumbnail4"></div>
<a href="#" id="link">click me to fade in</a>
```